# (ASP.NET Core) How to update view component on view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

When I select a item (ul,li),
I need to update the view component dynamically,but cannot achieve.

How do I modify the code ?

Do not use (Controller)"return view" method

(Partial code)
(chtml)

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="tab"> <a href="#" onclick=change1();>1</a></li>
        <li role="tab"> <a href="#" onclick=change2();>2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
    @{
        string item = ViewBag.NowPay;
        switch (item)
        {
            case "Card1":
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("DownloadConfig1", new { reconciliationConfig = Model });
                break;
            case "Card2":
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("DownloadConfig2", new { reconciliationConfig = Model });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
</div>
```

(script)

```
function change1() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ReconciliationConfig/TestChane1',
        success: function (data) {

        }

    })
}
```

Controller

```
public String TestChane1()
{
    ViewBag.NowPay = "Card1";
    var Result = ViewBag.NowPay;
    return Result;
}
```

Thanks for answer

Comment: the `Switch Statement` will not re-compiled again on the client-side, you have to return a Partial View after Compiling it on server-side

Comment: Can use    "  $('#  (div's id)  ').html(     (code)     );    "   method?

Comment: yes, but you have first render the `switch` on server-side , you return only `string`

Comment: ".html ()" seems to fail, I tried the following answer

Comment: The content of "view component" is a form, which seems to be more suitable for the following answer

Comment: you tried the solution in first answer ?

Comment: Still trying, no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Solution**

if you don't want to go again to server, you have to render `each` case in separate div and show/hide with `javascript`

View Code `cshtml`

```
<style>
.d-none, .hidden { display: none; }
</style>

<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="tab"> <a href="#" onclick=change('Card1');>1</a></li>
        <li role="tab"> <a href="#" onclick=change('Card2');>2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
    @{
        string item = ViewBag.NowPay;
    }

    <div id="Card1" class="cards @(item == "Card1" ? "" : "hidden d-none")">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("DownloadConfig1", new { reconciliationConfig = Model });
    </div>

    <div id="Card2" class="cards @(item == "Card2" ? "" : "hidden d-none")">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("DownloadConfig2", new { reconciliationConfig = Model });
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function change(name) {
        $('.cards').addClass('hidden d-none'); // hide all cards
        $('#'+ name).removeClass('hidden d-none'); // show only one
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have not  use the "ViewBag" of answer ?  QAQ

Comment: `ViewBag.NowPay` is used to show the Default Shown Div after  page load, you can remove it and wait to the user click

Comment: I updated the code below and it does not dispaly successfully

Answer (score 1):

Not currently successful
cshtml

```
<style>
.d-none, .hidden { display: none; }
</style>

<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li role="tab"> <a href="#" onclick=changeCard1();>1</a></li>
         <li role="tab"> <a href="#" onclick=changeCard2();>2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
    <div id="Card1" class="d-none">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("DownloadConfig1", new { reconciliationConfig = Model });
    </div>

    <div id="Card2" class="d-none">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("DownloadConfig2", new { reconciliationConfig = Model });
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function changeCard1() {
      $('Card1').removeClass('d-none');  // show only one
      $('Card2').addClass('d-none');
                       }

function changeCard2() {
      $('Card1').addClass('d-none');  // show only one
      $('Card2').removeClass('d-none');  // show only one
                       }
</script>
```

Comment: `changeCard2` is not defined

Comment: "function ", it does not dispaly successfully

Comment: the `Selector` is wrong, add `#` in `$('#Card1')` and `$('#Card2')`

Comment: Sorry, thank you very much.
It can run successfully.